# How to export some extent of a vector layer to canvas as an image in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

How to export some extent of a vector layer to canvas as an image in OpenLayers? Something like `VectorLayer.render(HtmlCanvasElement, {zoom, extent})`.

Comment: You should be able to do it the same way as the export examples https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/export-map.html https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/export-pdf.html  Both create a canvas before exporting it as png or pdf.  Size and scale the map as necessary to fit the extent to the zoom or resolution as in the pdf export, and use setVisible() to hide layers you don't want.

Comment: @Mike, I don't want to offend openlayers developers, but if you'll look at that example from objective perspective, as a good programmer, don't you think that their method of exporting map is a little strange?

Comment: It's like that because the map may consist of multiple canvases, some at the device pixel ratio, some not, some rotated with the view, some not.  The code is also IE compatible.  You will find third-party exports e.g.  https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/src/control/Print.js use similar code.

Comment: Don't understand what difficulty multiple canvases make. There must be internal code that renders a layer, I'm trying now to find it and redirect to external canvas.

Comment: For a single layer you could use `layer.on('postrender', function(event) {  } );` and access the canvas using `event.context.canvas`;  Set the `className` option in the layer constructor to a unique value to ensure the layer will not share a canvas

Comment: I need not just current view, but render it with specific dpi. So my thoughts: create invisible canvas on the document; call the code that renders this layer but replace layer's canvas with my canvas and layer's extent with specific extent; after rendering get picture of canvas; delete canvas.

Comment: I found method `renderFrame` but it demands `frameState` parameter and the documentation about it is something incredible. It says that `frameState` is "Frame state"!